# What is the default value of the CSS property `resize`?

Tags: css, resize, textarea

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp) says “Default value: `none`”.

But [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize) says “In many browsers, `<textarea>` elements are resizable by default.”

So why is that?

In my experience, it’s always working as the second one. But I get confused when looking at the default value (`none`) showed on some tech pages.

Comment: it's like `display`, the default value is inline but many element have display:block (div, p, section, etc) and some have different display like table, ul, li, etc

Comment: It’s easier to just ignore anything written on W3Schools.